# Call a spring servlet from Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm new with spring MVC and I'm trying to access a spring servlet from my Java application and print the result. But I can't make it working. I can access a index.jsp file from the navigator at url : http://localhost:8080/MyApp/
But my main class raise me an exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/MyApp/helloWorld. 
Can anyone help me ?

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MyApp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <!-- will look for application-servlet.xml file to load -->
        <servlet-name>application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My application-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.server.controllers" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.server.managers" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.server.repositories" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My spring controller

```
@Controller
public class ApplicationController {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationManager applicationManager;

     @RequestMapping("/helloWorld.do")
     public String helloWorld() {
        return "helloWorld";
     }

}
```

My Java code

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/helloWorld";

        URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
        InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();

        System.out.println(response.read());
    }

}
```

Comment: do you have a jsp called "helloWorld"? because spring is trying to find it, thats why you get the exception.

Comment: Are you implying that when you open `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/helloWorld` in a normal web browser it works fine? If also not then this problem has nothing to do with `URLConnection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for answering.
Reading your post and some documentation on googlefriend, I finally solved my issue.
Of course, this needs to be done in my case :

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And then in the spring controller :

```
     @RequestMapping("/helloWorld.do")
     public @ResponseBody String connexionApplication() {
        return "Hello World !";
     }
```

So finally if I call "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/helloWorld" from my browser or from my java code it returns me Hello World !

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are trying to hit a non existing endpoint.
You map the @RequestMapping("/helloWorld.do") and you are trying to call the /helloWorld

Try to rename your request mapping to @RequestMapping("/helloWorld")

If you want to use .do try to add

`<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>`

to your servlet mapping

Here you can find a spring mvc show case

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase

Hope it helps.

Comment: The .do convention is a leftover from Struts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain you .do extension then replace your servlet mapping as follows.

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Also remove the .do extension in @RequestMapping("/helloWorld.do") to be @RequestMapping("/helloWorld").By default Spring matches /helloWorld plus any extension i.e /helloWorld.do , /helloWorld.htm  etc

This provides flexibility in that you only need to change your servlet mapping in web.xml to use a different extension

In your test class use the url http://localhost:8080/MyApp/helloWorld.do